# Equality between a fonction and an infinite serie.

Tags: derivatives, power-series

I want to prove this equality :

-ln(x+1) = S(from 1 to infinite) ((-x)^n/n) //for x between -1 and 1 (not included of course).

I wrote on my notebook : show the derivates are equals and the two sides equals for a particular x.
But, when i derivate the Sum, i don't see how that helps me ..

Can someone remind me what i wanted to do ? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Generalized binomial theorem or Infinite Geometric Series for $|x|<1$

$$(1+x)^{-1}=1-x+x^2-\cdots=\sum_{1\le r<\infty}(-1)^{r-1}x^{r-1}$$

Now integrate either sides $$\ln(1+x)=C+\sum_{1\le r<\infty}(-1)^{r-1}\frac{x^r}r\  \ \  \ (1)$$ where $C$ is an arbitrary [constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_integration)

Now, set $x=0$ in $(1)$ to find $C$

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly !

I don't see why you've integrated .. after expressing (1+x)^-1 = S(from r=0 to infinite) (-x)^r, I just have to derivate the other side and then done .. No ?

The infinite geometric series thing is really cool btw, never thought of it when n-->infinite ^^

Comment: @Pac, my method is to derive the expression of $\ln(1+x)$. Yours is to verify the expression.

Comment: i see now what the difference, probably yours more beautiful !

Comment: But i'm sure that my problem is done now, so thank you :)

Comment: @Pac, my pleasure